# Can I ask for programming advice on this site?

Tags: support

The question is in the title. 
This is the most direct question ever.

Answer (score 6):

### Yes, if..

- It relates to Ubuntu
- It's not too opinionated
- It doesn't trip over one of the other "[don't ask](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask)" formats.

Comment: What do you mean by: It relates to Ubuntu?

Comment: I mean exactly that. Are you using Ubuntu, are you deploying to Ubuntu, does this in some way interface with Ubuntu... It's quite a wide margin. It's also hard to give you some sort of decision when we're only talking in abstracts. Ask your question. See what happens :)